# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ucrtd.lib' in VS2017 RC

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors, visual-studio-2017

I keep getting an error when I build a C++ project in Visual Studio 2017 RC.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: test, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Source.cpp
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ucrtd.lib'
1>Done building project "test.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

OS: Windows 8.1, Visual Studio 2017 Release Candidate

Here is my program:

```
int main()
{
}
```

I did not set the language to anything special

[image]

I searched my whole machine for the file., but could not find it.
I have installed Windows SDK 8.1

Update:
After the comment from @user1336087

I tried to install Windows SDK 10I get an error:

```
[14f0:0009][2016-11-23T09:22:20] Package 'Win10SDK_10.0.14393.33,version=10.0.14393.3300' failed to install. Command executed: "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Win10SDK_10.0.14393.33,version=10.0.14393.3300\packages\Win10SDK\10.0.14393.33\sdksetup.exe" /features OptionId.WindowsSoftwareDevelopmentKit OptionId.WindowsSoftwareLogoToolkit OptionId.NetFxSoftwareDevelopmentKit /quiet /norestart, Return code: -2146889721, Details: The hash value is not correct.
```

A workaround seems to have been described here: [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/11/16/visual-studio-2017-rc/)
But the workaround still fails, even when I uninstall all SDK and install again.

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7a2f61b7-3c01-4767-9a30-e897dc240e60/lnk1104-cannot-open-file-ucrtdlib?forum=vssetup) will help!

Comment: Actually the Windows SDK 10 installation error that you got is different from the one you referred to in the link. Your error indicates that the file is corrupted. Please try to redownload the Windows SDK 10 and attempt to install it again.

Comment: It is downloading from Internet when I install it..

Comment: but it fails after the download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in the final version of Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 0):

This comment here helped me with the same error. It seems having old versions of the Windows SDK present can cause LINK to get confused. Deleting the old version I had fixed the problem.

https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/LINK-fatal-error-LNK1104-cannot-open-file-ucrtd-lib-with-VS2015/td-p/1060422